# Netlogo - how to read a part of the data from txt/CSV files during simulation

Tags: netlogo

I have a very big file containing a list of parcels information. I modeled each parcel as an agent with unique properties in my model. There are a total of 2.3 M parcels.

The problem is that if I file-read all parcels and create them as agents at one time during setup, it will occupy a large amount of memory and potentially will cause OOM at the initial few ticks. Therefore, I have to change the strategy to import data and create agents in batches during the simulation run.

my data looks like in this shape for example: The first column is the arrival time in minutes and the second is the attribute per each parcel. I run my simulation model one tick = one minute so all parcels with the same arrival minute will be activated for certain actions and once they finish they will die

```
arr_time    property
94  T6
197 T4
202 T4
252 T6
252 T6
252 T4
252 T6
252 T6
252 T6
252 T6
252 T6
252 T6
252 T6
252 T6
252 T6
252 T6
252 T6
252 T6
252 T6
252 T6
252 T6
252 T6
252 T6
252 T6
252 T6
665 T4
665 T6
665 T6
665 T6
665 T6
665 T4
846 T4
1355    T4
1407    T6
1411    T6
1426    T6
1426    T6
1426    T6
1426    T6
```

the actual file is much bigger than this. Instead of reading them once at a time I would like to read the file multiple times during the simulation run, e.g. run file-read command every 120 ticks (minutes) to read next 120 minutes data and create agents who arrive during this period. Thereby, the total number of agents in my simulation world can be reduced to prevent "Out of Memory" especially when parallel runs are executed. (I prefer file-read with .txt files by the way)

Comment: Won't you still get an memory out of bounds issue towards the end as all of the agents are being loaded? You may want to step back and question whether there's a benefit in modeling all of them or if you can find a trend given the initial sets of agents. Alternatively, this may be a good candidate for the fly-weight pattern.

Comment: I won't face OOM as the agents who finish their tasks will die so the total number of agents at a specific time won't be the total number of agents. This can speed up my model dramatically. I have to model each parcel explicitly because it has different directions and other attributes for sorting and transportation purpose. The model is for solving real problem so the actual parcel waybill number is tied to each parcel. I cannot reduce the population which is different from academic research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give a good ol' file-io example. I'm particularly not going to use the csv extension because it'll read the full file in.

Essentially, the idea is, load the agents line by line of the file if it's the current tick. You'll need to parse your line and convert the arr-time to an int. You would also need to call this function each tick in your simulation (costs time, but saves in space!)

```
to load-agents
   file-open "my-file.txt"
   while [not file-at-end?]
   [
     let line file-readline
     let delimiter-index position " " line
     let arr-time read-from-string substring 0 delimiter-index
     let property substring (delimiter-index + 1) length line
     if arr-time > ticks [file-close stop]
     if arr-time = ticks [load-agent arr-time property]
   ] 
end
```

Comment: Many thanks but I dont want the model to read the file on every tick it will slow down the model significantly. I am thinking a way to read the data for next 120 ticks so I only need to read the data 12 times during my simulation time (1440 min or 24hrs as the running length). One way I can do is to use csv:from-file "parcel.csv" to load all data into lists of lists and perform the data extraction from the list to generate agents every 120 ticks for next 120 ticks. Or I can still use file-read to import the data and group them as lists attached to table keys.

Comment: Right, so my suggestion is to follow the same trend of keep reading from the list until the arrival time is large, then kill the loading function.  Or, you can trigger the loading function to occur every ticks 120 time steps (if ticks mod 120 = 0 [load-next-agents ticks]). If you store the text file in as an array, you can just use the ticks to keep track of the current index and keep reading from the list until the the arr-time - 120 > ticks

Comment: I have successfully done it. My model speed improve 10 times higher. Originally I need more than 30 min to run but now only 3 min. Hence it can be concluded that the number of agents simultaneously existed in the model will affect largely the speed of simulation and memory usage.